# hanging multiple picture frames of different sizes in line and with equal spacing

Tags: drywall, hanging, design

Im putting up a picture wall of multiple picture frames of varying sizes.
The first picture below gives a very rough idea of what im trying to achieve, all in line at top where two are inline.

I didnt consider a few complications that are making this more difficult than expected.

1. the frames are deep and only have a sawtooth hanger so i will have to use string.(Was thinking of just putting a loop of string around the sawtooth and hooking that onto the hook.)
2. the sawtooth is different distances from the top of the frame on the different sizes of frame(2nd picture below).

This means i need to ensure the string is the right length for each frame to keep the tops of the frames in line and judging this is a nightmare.

The hooks i am using are these(3rd picture below), as its a sheetrock stud wall.
I feel like im making a mountain out of this.

Appreciate any advice on how to achieve my end goal, but few frames missing.

[image: Rough estimation of end goal]
Rough estimation of end goal

[image: varying heights of sawtooth hangers]
varying heights of sawtooth hangers

[image: hooks]
hooks

Comment: attaching the string (or wire) to the frame is probably better than trying to use a string  to an offset sawtooth,  the sawtooth might pull out.

Answer (score 1):

Forget the sawtooths. Buy some picture wire and small screws. I like short #6 panheads for most pictures. Maybe #8 for large pictures.

Attach the screws about 1/3 from the top on each side. Drill pilot holes so you don't split the wood. Don't screw them all the way in, leave room to wrap the wire.

Attach the picture wire so the hook will be inside the frame recess. Wrap around each screw and twist the wire on itself.

Buy or make a picture hanging tool. To make one, start with a stick about a foot long. Put a hook on one end and a cabinet knob on the other end. You can substitute many things for the knob, you just need something that will allow you to hold the stick while the picture is attached. The hook will be down and the knob will be up. Measure up 8 inches from the hook and put a mark.

[https://www.amazon.com/Picture-Hanging-Level-Hanger-Yellow/dp/B083J75P7F](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B083J75P7F)
https://www.bobvila.com/articles/picture-hanging-tips/ (see tip number 4)

Hang the picture on the tool and position it on the wall. Put a small mark on the wall at the mark on the stick.

Measure 8 inches down from the mark on the wall and nail in the hook to the wall.